How to assign controllers dynamically in duplicated textformfields?
In this diagram, there are 3 textformfields, which are inside container and which is inside a Listviewbuilder, controllers for those textformfields are assinged dynamically by:

List<TextEditingController> controllers =List.generate(10, (i) => TextEditingController());

controller: controllers[index],

There is a button called 'Dupilcate Above', when that button is clicked a same container with the same number of textformfield is created below. Like shown in second image. The problem is the duplicated textformfileds share the controllers.

For example: If I type 'apple', 'mango', 'orange' in first textformfields then dupicate them with 'Dupilcate Above' btn the below textformfields will also have same texts. How do I fix this?

Why is the length of your controllers list set to 10 yet you have 3 TextFormFields?

@SheldonOsotsi Initially, UI had 10 Textformfields that's why

For this, you'd probably want the input field to be its own widget that generates a new controller for itself. Then, you could have that widget include a callback for when the value is changed. This would let you define any number of fields dynamically, while still having access to the values. Here's a working example:
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              count++;
            });
          },
          child: const Text("Add"),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: count,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return MyTextField(
                key: ValueKey(index),
                index: index,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print("Input ${index + 1}: $value");
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTextField({
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.index,
    super.key,
  });

  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final int index;

  @override
  State<MyTextField> createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: "Input ${widget.index + 1}",
      ),
    );
  }
}

